# No bookmark icon next to bookmark item in Safari 8.0.7 (Yosemite 10.10.4)

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks

In Safari 8.0.7 (Yosemite 10.10.4) when I hit **"⇧ ⌘ B"** my Favorites Bar appears and I can see my bookmarks as well as all folders but one thing I'm really missing are favicon right before bookmarks.

[image]

As you can see, Safari is able to display them under "Edit Bookmarks" (**⌥ ⌘ B**). Is there a way to display them in the place I highlighted green dots on the screen above?

Am I missing something? Does it require additional extension?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too miss that, I actually use Chrome at the moment, and it was one of the big things I missed.

Unfortunately there is no way to recover this behaviour, Safari is a much faster browser option on OS X than Chrome or Firefox at the moment.

I choose to use Chrome still, but you might just get used to it...

Comment: Thank you for clarification. On the one hand I like the simplicity of the OS X interface but from the other one this look like a significant missing feature. I don't like to base on assumptions but I wonder if this will be added in El Captain or newer version of Safari or maybe 3rd party extension should be installed (while I haven't found anything that could do this)... Anyway - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky enough to still have your bookmarks bar, this worked for me:
I went to the web page I wanted to bookmark, highlighted the entire URL, then dragged it onto the bar. Voila!